# Check Small Screen support in android

Tags: android

I have put below code in android manifest file. So My app will not work in small size screens.

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" >
</supports-screens>
```

But now when I run application in small screen device via eclipse, it can be install.
If i want to check that small screen device cannot dwonload app from google play store how can I test?
I want to check before uploading to the play store.

Comment: Have you tried to download from store to  small device? Think, it can't be supported based on manifest restrictions.

Comment: yes, I think same as Lokesh

Comment: Still I haven't uploaded. Before I publish I want to confirm.

Comment: @nil do u find the solution from my answer??

Answer (score 1):

You can not test without publishing app on playstore because only `Google Play` takes care of it.

```
To do so, you can enable filtering by external services such as Google Play by adding 
elements to your manifest file that specify the screen configurations your application 
supports.

External services such as Google Play use this information to apply filtering to your 
application, so that only devices that have a screen configuration with which you declare   
compatibility can download your application.
```

Fore more information [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Publish your app via google play and check what devices will be rejected from use. If devices like HTC Wildfire is disabled you can be sure that small devices are not supported in your app.

Answer (score 0):

When developers make apps, they have to specify any hardware/software requirements in a file called the androidmanifest.xml file.

These can be hardware or software requirements, such as if the app needs GPS, or telephony features - or if it will only work on a certain Android version.

**When you use Google Play, it sends your device's 'features' to the server, and then filters apps accordingly.**

The most likely reason it is deemed incompatible by Google Play is that it is set to require a certain screen resolution - or maybe portrait/landscape mode defaults.

Some tablets have a low resolution, and also tell google play that they cannot go into portrait mode.

It could also be, your tablet being generic, that it does not have the required GPS or sensors that the manifiest file says it needs, and the market is stopping you from installing because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can test by uploading apk file into the Google Play service.

#### But, dont publish.

Try to download/browse from/in Google Play in small screen devices. Make use of Sandbox.

Comment: @nil do u find the solution from my answer?/